# How to configure Dependency Injection in my own class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.1

I wish to use settings from appsettings.json in my own class.

I have this working well in a controller and in razor.  I tried to use the same code as in a controller in my own class:

```
public class Email
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Email(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
```

but when I try to call this

```
Email sendEmail = new Email();
```

it requires that I provide config as a parameter.  Shouldn't the DI system provide (inject) this? In ConfigureServices I have this:

```
services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
```

Do I need to register Email class somewhere too?  Do I need to call it some different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the following code:

```
Email sendEmail = new Email();
```

The DI system isn't involved at all - You've taken things into your own hands. Instead, you should add `Email` to the DI system and then have *it* injected. e.g.:

```
services.AddSingleton<Email>(); // You might prefer AddScoped, here, for example.
```

Then, as an example, if you're accessing `Email` in a controller, you can have it injected too:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly Email _email;

    public SomeController(Email email)
    {
        _email = email;
    }

    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
         // Use _email here.
         ...
    }
}
```

Essentially, this just means you need to use DI all the way. If you want to provide more details about *where* you're currently creating your `Email` class, I can tailor the examples more to that.

---

It's a bit of an side, but you can also inject dependencies using the `[FromServices]` attribute inside of an action. Using this means you can skip the constructor and private field approach. e.g.:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult SomeAction([FromServices] Email email)
    {
         // Use email here.
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kirk, thanks for the answer so far.
Email is created inside another ordinary class.
The real problem is how do I get access to the appsettings config info inside a (non-controller) class?  And maybe using the constructor/DI is not the correct way.

Comment: The answer is still the same in this case. The recommended approach is to use DI all the way to the top. I expect that a controller is what starts your code running at some level - the answer is to add the *other ordinary class* to the DI system and inject *that* into your controller. It might be worth adding more details to your question describing the classes involved here.

Comment: Yes the controller starts it one level up.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you defined a constructor which requires the parameter.

Please check out the concept of [Class Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors).

Injection is design pattern, when we use class and interfaces to implement it, it should still follow the basic Class methodology and concept.
Hope it helps.